# Pentaho 6.0.1 connection to Mapr 5.0.1

Tags: pentaho, mapr, pentaho-spoon

I am trying to connect Pentaho DI to Mapr. While creating a connection I get the following error
Unable to load the {0}Shim.

I am using Pentaho Enterprise edition.

Has anyone faced similar issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the pentaho-mapr .jar file in the lib folder of PDI?, for example if you want to connect to mysql database then first you probably need to install the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar` file

Comment: .jar files are available in the folder Pentaho\design-tools\data-integration\plugins\pentaho-big-data-plugin\hadoop-configurations\mapr410\lib

Comment: may be you would require some additional .jars